# Road Type in Google Maps API

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google Maps API.
In my Swift iOS app, I have current location coordinates. While reverse geocoding, how do I get the road type (highway, primary, secondary etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to use [Road API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/) for that.

Roads API identifies the roads a vehicle was traveling along and provides additional metadata about those roads, such as speed limits.